# Woocommerce action hook to execute function on subscription renewal

Tags: wordpress

I want to know if there is a action hook that can check if the subscription is successfully renewed in woocommerce ? BTW I am using woocommerce subscription plugin. I have created a functionality that records the date of the subscription order and add it to a CSV file, the function is working perfectly for the first purchase I mean when the user purchase a subscription it is recorded successfully in the CSV because I am firing up the function on woocommerce_thankyou action hook, The only issue I am facing is that I can't seem to find a hook which can execute this function on successful subscription renewal. I tried to use woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete action hook but it didn't worked below is the function that I have created.

```
/**
 * Add subscriptions to csv.
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'add_subs_to_csv' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_subs_to_csv' );
function add_subs_to_csv( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
        $meta_values = $value->get_data();
        foreach ( $meta_values as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
            if ( $meta_key == 'product_id' && $meta_value == 875 ) {
                $paid_date      = explode( " ", get_post_meta( $order_id, '_paid_date', true ) );
                $subs_paid_date = date( 'd F, Y', strtotime( $paid_date[0] ) );
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $key, 'Delivery Date', $subs_paid_date );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Could the [`wcs_renewal_order_created`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/#section-5) hook be what you're looking for? The docs say:

> WooCommerce Subscriptions stores all details of each subscription
> renewal in a standard WooCommerce order, only with a special meta flag
> linking it to a subscription.
>
> These orders are always created through the **wcs_create_renewal_order()**
> function, regardless of whether they are created for a scheduled
> renewal event, manually via the WooCommerce > Edit Subscription
> administration screen, or via the Subscriptions endpoints for the
> WooCommerce REST API. Because of this, it’s possible to add, remove or
> update the value of anything on that renewal order using this filter.
>
> For example, this can be used to add a discount to specific renewal
> orders, like the 12th order each year. It could also be used to add
> one-time fee for a certain renewal order, like a special annual extra
> fee on a monthly subscription.

So the above hook should trigger after payment, you'd probably just need to check if it was completed status which you could also do in your current hooks:

```
/**
 * After WooCommerce Subscriptions Creates Renewal Order
 *
 * @param WC_Order Object $order
 * @param Integer|WC_Subscription Object $subscription
 *
 * @return WC_Order $order
 */
function add_subs_to_csv( $order, $subscription ) {

    if( 'completed' === $order->get_status() ) {
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
            $meta_values = $value->get_data();
            foreach ( $meta_values as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
                if ( $meta_key == 'product_id' && $meta_value == 875 ) {
                    $paid_date      = explode( " ", get_post_meta( $order_id, '_paid_date', true ) );
                    $subs_paid_date = date( 'd F, Y', strtotime( $paid_date[0] ) );
                    wc_add_order_item_meta( $key, 'Delivery Date', $subs_paid_date );
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $order

}
add_filter( 'wcs_renewal_order_created', 'add_subs_to_csv', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I am working on the same stuff, well almost the same, I will implement your suggestion and see if it works ... will report back .. Thanks

Comment: `return $order` at the end of the function is needed

Comment: Do we know if this hook actually DOES fire after payment? The way it reads is vague, to me, and in my case is a very important consideration.

Comment: @armadadrive The easiest thing to do is test it. Always test the code you get elsewhere. You can read more about the hook in the [WooCommerce Subscription docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/#section-5).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I agree fully, just hadn't gotten a clear answer from the dev docs and wondered if anyone had any concrete knowledge before I began testing my own solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @armadadrive Sorry, this has been so long ago I also don't know for sure. If you find out please edit it into the answer for future readers!

Comment: `wcs_renewal_order_created` is a filter, not an action hook and hence its proper usage is `add_filter`, rather than `add_action`. You'll find it in `class-wc-subscriptions-renewal-order.php`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a issue at Subscription renewal and I got it fixed with below code:

```
/*
 * FIXED : Membership got PAUSED everytime at automatic subscription renewal
 */

function change_membership_status_active( $subscription , $order ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( 'completed' === $order->get_status() ) {        
        $membership = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_subscription_id' AND meta_value =  $subscription->ID" );
        $mem_id = $membership->post_id;
        $status = 'wcm-active';
        $update_args = array( 'ID' => $mem_id, 'post_status' => $status );
        wp_update_post($update_args);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'change_membership_status_active', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/206345)